# Rspec expected nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I try to test my controller with Rspec:

```
let(:valid_attributes) {
        FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:job)
    }

....

describe "GET #new" do
        it "assings a new job" do
            get :new
            expect(assigns(:job)).to be_a_new(Job)
        end
    end
```

my factories:

```
  FactoryGirl.define do
   factory :job do
    title "MyString"
    description "MyDescription"
    city "MyCity"
    date Date.today
    job_end false
    user
   end
  end
```

schema.rb:

```
create_table "jobs", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.text     "description"
t.string   "city"
t.datetime "date"
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
t.integer  "user_id"
t.boolean  "job_end"
end
```

and an error that I got:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:job)).to be_a_new(Job)
   expected nil to be a new Job(id: integer, title: string, description: text, city: string, date: datetime, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, user_id: integer, job_end: boolean)
```

I understand that my Job object which create is wrong? Or what? Can you explain me a little bit?

my controller:

```
  def new
    @job = current_user.jobs_given.build
  end

  def create
    @job = current_user.jobs_given.build(job_params)

    if @job.save
        redirect_to @job
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Comment: can you provide your controller's code?

Comment: did you check your controller returns success response?

Comment: No, how can I do that? Sorry, but I just started to learn it.

Comment: insert this "expect(response).to have_http_status(200)" after "get :new"

Comment: Ok, after added this I've got this error`expected the response to have status code 200 but it was 302`

Comment: did you use device gem?

Comment: yes, I sign_in user in this way `def setup
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:user)
   end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because device gem redirect your to sign_in_path, because you sign in your user incorrect. You should do this at the top of your controller test:

```
before(:each) do
    request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:user)
end
```

And better way is create sign in method and call it in every controller. See here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-%28and-RSpec%29 (Controllers spec section)

Comment: Thank  you very much!